# Пересоздать view-элементы

Tags: android

Нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки пересоздавались все view-элементы из XML. Т.е. вернуть к исходному состоянию. 
Просто перезапуск активити мне не подходит, потому что в onCreate есть метод который загружает ранее сохраненное состояние.

Comment: по клику в обратном порядке менять каждый view. Просто неизвестно что именно у них поменялось

Comment: А можно поподробнее?

Comment: не могу подробней, так как мне неизвестно, что с вашими view происходило, после чего их надо вернуть к изначальному состоянию

Answer (score 0):

Допустим у вас есть вьюшка `child` с лейаутом `R.layout.child`, которая находится внутри `myLayout`, тогда делаем так:

```
View child=(View )myLayout.findViewById(R.id.child); //находим вьюшку
myLayout.removeView(child); //удаляем ее
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null); //заново пересоздаем
myLayout.addView(child); //прицепляем обратно
```

Comment: Третья строчка не работает.

Comment: @Рома я не компилятор, я написал на коленках общую идею, дальше уже сами.

Comment: Если у меня у меня button1 размещена на constraintLayout1, то 3 строчка как должна выглядеть? 'button1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(constraintLayout1, null);' Так?